# Problema em converter os valores do input em Reais, exemplo: R$ 20,00

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

> Criei um Script para formatar valores do Input para Moedas Reais, porém tem um problema, quando coloca texto, apresentar "Nan", preciso que só possa digitar numero e não texto.

```js
var atual = document.querySelector('.form-control');
atual.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  var valor = parseInt(this.value);
  var valor2 = valor.toLocaleString("pt-br", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "BRL"
  });
  atual.value = valor2;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Moedas</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="form-area-imovel" class="form-control">
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: input type="number" nao resolve teu problema?

Comment: Na minha opinião a melhor forma seria usar uma lib de mascaras, como o @Vinicius.Silva recomendou.

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa fazer algumas checagens antes de formatar o valor. São elas:

1. Remover a moeda (R$) caso o usuário a digite
2. Verificar se o valor digitado é um número ou não com [isNaN](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)

Veja o código abaixo:

```js
var atual = document.querySelector('.form-control');

function sanitizeValor (valor) {
 var valorSemCurrency = valor.replace(/r\$\s?/i, '');
 return isNaN(valorSemCurrency) ? 0 : parseFloat(valorSemCurrency);
}

atual.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  /**
   * Você pode ler da seguinte forma esse if ternário
   *
   *  If is Not a Number (isNaN) this.value então 0 caso contrário this.value
   */
  var valor = sanitizeValor(this.value);
  var valor2 = valor.toLocaleString("pt-br", {
 style: "currency",
 currency: "BRL"
  });
  atual.value = valor2;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Moedas</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="form-area-imovel" class="form-control">
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

O problema dessa abordagem é que uma coisa aparentemente simples começa a se tornar custosa a medida que você vai testando a "remendando o código" para cada situção. Por exemplo se o usuário digitar os centavos com essa abordagem eles serão removidos, se você quiser tratar isso vai ter que remover os pontos e virgulas tratar o a entrada para ver se o usário digitou a currency e etc...

Nesse seu cenário eu sugiro que você use uma máscara nesse campo que fará todo esse trabalho para você e impedirá que o usuário digite texto ao invés de números.

Um plugin muito utilizado é o [jQuery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) veja o exemplo acima utilizando máscaras.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.money').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
});
```

```css
.input-group {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 20px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">R$</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control money" placeholder="0,00" aria-label="Valor" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

Comment: Você, meu amigo, fez um trabalho primoroso e simples! Parabéns e obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Ve se isso te ajuda.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function mascara(o,f){
    v_obj=o
    v_fun=f
    setTimeout("execmascara()",1)
}
function execmascara(){
    v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
}

function mnum(v){
    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");                                      //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    return v;
}

function id( el ){
    return document.getElementById( el );
}

function next( el, next )
{
    if( el.value.length >= el.maxLength ) 
        id( next ).focus(); 
}
</script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="valor" name="valor" placeholder="" onkeypress="mascara(this, mvalor);">
```